# run method works but thread won't call it

Tags: java

I have to implement a class that stores information about an airport for a school project. The class is supposed to read data about flights and passenger info from websites written in HTML that our instructor has provided us with, and in order to do this, we are using threads. My problem is that when I call the start() method on my thread, it won't call the run method on my class that implements runnable, which is strange because when I first tested the program and called the run() method directly, it worked just fine. This is the while loop that is inside the run method of my worker class which does the actual data processing.

```
while (1 == 1) {
    temp = scan.next();
    if ((temp.equals("</body>")))
        break;
    else {
        name = temp;
        flightNum = scan.nextInt();
        city = scan.next();
        indexOfBR = city.indexOf("<");
        city = city.substring(0, indexOfBR);

        synchronized (airplanes) {
            addFlight(flightNum, city);
            addPassengerReservation(flightNum, name);
        }
    }
}
scan.close();
```

The loop is supposed to read a passenger name then a flight number and then a destination city, stored in the html file as:

```
"passenger name" "flight Number" "destination city"<br>
```

The method that creates and runs the thread is

```
public void readFlightData(String[] urls) {
    for (int x = 0; x < urls.length; x++) {
        if (!(urls[x].equals(""))) {
            try {
                Worker w = new Worker(new URL(urls[x]));
                Thread work = new Thread(w);
                work.start();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method does not call the run method when i call start on the work thread and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I've identified the problem as being in the synchronized block in the while loop. The object being passed to the synchronized block, airplanes, is an ArrayList meant to hold information about flights and passengers in the Airport class. the addFlight() method is meant to add a flight with flightNum and destination city. addPassengerReservation adds a passenger to the indicated flightNum with name "name"

Comment: Is the line `work = new Thread(w);` actually running?  Maybe you should log that `MalformedURLException`, just so that you know it's happened.

Comment: I went back and did that. The thread is running. Or at the very least, the code did not throw a MalformedURLException. Additionally, when I ran the code by directly calling w.run() it worked, and I am using the same urls now as I did then

Comment: Just to tell, in spite of `while(1 == 1)` you can also write `while(true)` directly to create an infinite loop.

Comment: I just called isAlive on  work and the thread is in fact alive. Is it a coding problem in the actual class work? I'm very confused

Comment: Sounds like you need to start using your debugger.

Comment: May be your args array is empty (i.e) urls. So it will never get into loop anyway...

Comment: That was the first thing I did before I posted here. I am using Eclipse. It just kind of jumps over the thread without really showing me what its doing. If I look at the window where it shows information about currently existing variables, it is either information I do not understand, since I am very new to threads, or it is information that does not help me

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Threads directly? Otherwise I would suggest to use an [ExecutorSevice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). How does the `run()` method look like. The `urls[x].equals("")` may cause a `NullPointerException`. A Null-Safe variant would be to write it as `"".equals(urls[x])`. You can set a BreakPoint at the start of the `run` method and in some additional line after `work.start()`. If it hits the BeakPoint at the additional line you should see the `worker` as variable and check the thread status.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement to use threads

Comment: My question seems to be not clear enough. Is it required to use the low level java Thread API or can you use something like [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html). Executors / FutureTasks makes it a lot easier to parallelize Tasks. Can you please post the whole Worker code and also the code that relevant code that invokes the `readFlightData(String[] urls)`

Comment: Why do you have zero-length URLs in your array?

Comment: I guess I should clarify the project requirements. It is a requirement to directly use the Thread class, which I assume is what you mean by the low level Thread API. The reason I zero-length urls in my code is because according to the project description, there is a possibility that a zero length url could be passed into the function, and my code must be prepared to deal with that

Answer (score 1):

The code is very brittle. I suggest the following changes. I think there is a MalformedURLException and you are hiding it.

```
public void readFlightData(String[] urls) {
    for (int x = 0; x < urls.length; x++) {
        if (!(urls[x].equals(""))) {
            try {
                Worker w = new Worker(new URL(urls[x]));
                Thread work = new Thread(w);
                work.start();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made these changes and the code did not throw an error, however, it still does not work. What exactly happens in the start method before it calls the run method of the object the thread is instantiated with? Maybe that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Instead of multiple urls, can you try running a thread for one url? this will be similar to your single execution.

Comment: Thats how I am testing it right now. urls[] has just one element

Comment: Just for testing can you comment out all code in your run method and put a simple System.out statement and see if that works? Another thing is just to comment out the syncrhonised block and see if that works

Comment: I added system.out statements and found out that there is a problem in the synchronized block in the while loop. It gets to the synchronized block but for some reason the method calls in that block don't modify the current object.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My problem was that I was calling methods on my Airport class before it had finished running the threads I had created and downloading the necessary information. I had to call join() on all of the threads to fix this problem. For those of you who were curios, here is the working code:

```
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
int x;

for (x = 0; x < urls.length; x++) {
    if (!(urls[x].equals(""))) {
        try {
            Worker w = new Worker(new URL(urls[x]));
            Thread work = new Thread(w);
            work.start();
            threads.add(work);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
    }
}

for (x = 0; x < threads.size(); x++)
    try {
        threads.get(x).join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Congratulations that you fixed the problem yourself. But how is the `join` related to `run()` is not invoked? btw. you should fix the handling of the `InterruptedException` by either re-setting the Interrupted Flag on the thread or by throwing the InterruptedException. "Brian Goetz" describes strategies to deal with InterruptedExceptions or even in this blog article [Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/)

Comment: It turns out that the thread was in fact calling run, however, I was just not aware of this through my tests because the Junit tests I was calling finished running before the threads i created finished downloading all the necessary information. This was causing the errors that were troubling me so much yesterday. By calling join in the method that creates the thread, I effectively stop the method from ending, and stop the Junit tests from running, until all of the threads have finished downloading their information.